# return outside if/else statement (Python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, theory

When you have the following code:

```
def func(a) -> Optional[S]
    if len(a) == 2:
         x = "bla bla bla"
    else:
        if a.state is True and len(a) == 3:
             s = "hello world"
    return s
```

Note: s is an instance of S.

I have two questions. Please answer them in order.

1. when you have the `return s` outside the inner `if` and right below the outer `else`, then after when would that return be executed? Will the return be executed after either of the conditions in the inner if is false?
2. What difference will it make if I do this instead, where the return is just outside the inner if now.

   ```
   def func(a) -> Optional[S]
      if len(a) == 2:
         x = "bla bla bla"
      else:
          if a.state is True and len(a) == 3:
             s = "hello world"
          return s
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1. It will be executed after the `if/else` code is executed, just like any other statement placed there. Note that you'll get an error if the `if` condition is true, or if neither condition is true, because in that case you never assign `s`.
2. If you move the `return` statement inside the `else:` it won't be executed when the `if` condition is true. IN that case the function will end with no `return` statement, so it will return `None` by default. This will avoid the error of trying to use `s` when the `if` condition is true, but it will still get an error if neither condition is true. The way to avoid that problem is to move the `return` into the innermost `if`:

```
def func(a) -> Optional[S]
    if len(a) == 2:
        x = "bla bla bla"
    else:
        if a.state is True and len(a) == 3:
            s = "hello world"
            return s
```

Also, we normally combine `else: if` into `elif`, so the code should be:

```
def func(a) -> Optional[S]
    if len(a) == 2:
        x = "bla bla bla"
    elif a.state is True and len(a) == 3:
        s = "hello world"
        return s
```